# How to integrate "WordNet Domains" into WordNet DB?

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet, jaws-wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

I am using `WordNet 2.1` `tool` and accessing it `pro-grammatically` via `JAWS`(`Java API for WordNet Searching`).

Today I came across this new thing called **WordNet Domains** which has assigned `DOMAIN` labels to each word in `WordNet`.

link:- http://wndomains.fbk.eu/labels.html

I have downloaded the same from above link. Its a zip file.

**My question is:-
How do I use "WordNet Domains" along with "WordNet" in Java?**

Comment: **My answer is:- Read the README**

Comment: Yes Qnan, I have read it. Specifically this is what I want - "wn-domains-3.2-20070223" contains the mapping between Princeton WordNet 2.0 synsets and their corresponding domains. **But they have not mentioned how to integrate this file into the wordnet database or is it that I have to programatically call this along with wordnet dict?** Can you clear my doubt.

Comment: Is it a way to integrate them somehow at all?

Comment: [This question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881425/get-wordnets-domain-name-for-the-specified-word/13919227#13919227) shows how to do it in Python. You could try something similar in Java.

Comment: Please post your current code (edited down to the vital information) plus your stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th answer is: The WNDomains project comes with a doc file that supplies the wordID and word domain. This wordID is the wordnet 2.1 wordID. So in java you can write a program thats maps the corresponding ID by mapping (reading doc file line by line)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using java, you can load the labels as a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`.

From personal experience, I would say instead of using Domain Labels, you can use values for the domains : Extended WordNet Domains project (http://adimen.si.ehu.es/web/XWND) on WordNet 3.0.