# Word of a particular domain from Wordnet

Tags: nltk, wordnet

I want to get all the words from Wordnet from a particular domain. What is the best way to do it? I have searched in NLTK Python package, but there is nothing there. Is there any API for that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "domain"? And what are you trying to do with these words?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881425/get-wordnets-domain-name-for-the-specified-word